# Should I cut off this weak branch on my crepe myrtle or try and support it?

Tags: trees, pruning

I have this great "pink velour" crepe myrtle tree that I planted last summer. I'm really happy with how fast it grows and how much it flowers. Recently, the weakest branch from the ground has started to sag really badly because of the weight of the bloom.

[image: crepe myrtle tree]

I'm wondering what a good approach would for fixing this. I don't want the branch to be trained into that position, I want it to grow up more. I could also just cut it off entirely, but it would leave that side a bit bare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the pic it is clear that there are a couple of egregious branches. The stems of the plant are in fact quite spindly and the same is likely to happen to other branches if no action taken. Crepe Myrtle can in fact be pruned quite hard and will benefit with both good flowering and a stronger structure. There are a number of pictures on the Internet showing examples where frighteningly hard pruning has resulted in a much stronger base over time (a bit like some rose pruning actually). Take heart and put in effect a pruning programme over the next few years that will result in a strong supporting structure. Reducing the mass at the top of those out of line right away will help restore the shape you are looking for, but leave major pruning for the dormant season.

Comment: So it's a few months later, and I did end up cutting off many of the low branches as suggested. I think it still looks great and it will fill out again in the spring. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing a little wiring can't fix. While pruning would work over time to help strengthen the branch if your interest is to keep the branch and prune in the winter then you simply need to wire; connect it to another stronger branch.